# Cannot create object in main

Tags: java

This question has been asked and answered here, but I can't find an example that makes sense to me. I am testing some code and trying to create an object in main from a class I made called Cube that inherits from a class called Solids that inherits from an abstract class called Shapes (I have to do it this way). My question is what can I do to fix the "AbstractShape.this cannot be referenced from a static context" error I am getting regarding my creation of cube1. Sorry if this is remedial, I am learning at the moment

```
public class AbstractShape {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Cube cube1 = new Cube(4,4,4);
        cube1.calcArea();
        cube1.print();
        Solids [] MySolids = new Solids[2];


    }
    abstract class Shapes{
        public abstract double getArea();
        public abstract double getVolume();
        public abstract String getName();
    }
    class Solids extends Shapes implements Comparable{
        protected int len;
        protected int wid;
        protected int hig;
        protected double area;
        protected double volume;
        public Solids(int len, int wid, int hig){




        }
        public int compareTo(Object o){
            if (getVolume() >((Shapes)o).getVolume())
                return 1;
            else
                if (getVolume()<((Shapes)o).getVolume())
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
        }
        public void setLen(int len){
            return;
        }
        public void setWid(int wid){
            return;
        }
        public void setHig(int hig){
            return;
        }
        public int getLen(){
            return len;
        }
        public int getWid(){
            return wid;
        }
        public int getHig(){
            return hig;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return "solid";
        }
        public double getArea(){
            return 0.0;
        }
        public double getVolume(){
            return 0.0;
        }
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("Solid of len"+len+" wid"+wid+" hig"+hig);
        }

    }

    class Cube extends Solids{
        protected int len;
        protected int wid;
        protected int hig;
        public Cube(int len, int wid, int hig){
            super(len,wid,hig);
            this.len=len;
            this.wid=wid;
            this.hig=hig;
        }
        public void calcArea(){
            area = 6*len*len;
        }
        public void calcVol(){
            volume = len*len*len;
        }
        public double getVolume(){
            return volume;
        }
        public double getArea(){
            return area;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return "Cube";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is because all of the class definitions are nested inside the definition for `AbstractShape`. This makes them “inner classes”, which is probably a concept you haven’t learned yet, and not what you intended. The solution is to move those other class definitions _after_ the closing brace (`}`) for the definition of `AbstractShape`.

Comment: Okay that fixed my issue, that makes sense. Thank you so much! Yes I'm not sure I've heard the concept before though I'll probably remember it now.

Comment: A better (all round) solution would be to move all your classes to their own files

Comment: That's what I would normally do and probably why I was confused in the first place, but I'm meant to be printing this out at the end to turn in and his  own example is one long mess so that's sort of how I started it

Comment: @TimMoore To be more specific, they aren't inner classes _only_ because they're nested. They're inner classes because they're nested _and non-static_ (note in Java, "inner class" as a specific meaning, and it means "non-static nested class"). Another solution would be to make them `static`.

Comment: @Thomas An inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class. This association _must_ exist. It's similar to how you can only access _instance_ fields/methods via an _instance_ of the class. A static nested class does not have such an association. They can be instantiated separately from the enclosing class. This is similar to how you can reference _static_ fields/methods via the class itself (rather than an _instance_ of the class). That means a solution is to make your inner classes into static nested classes. Though I would prefer separating them out into their own files.

Comment: @Thomas As an aside, see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/6395627). You have `implements Comparable`, but `Comparable` is a generic type and thus should be parameterized. That is to say, you should have something like `implements Comparable<Solids>` (and `compareTo(Solids other)`). Or perhaps, since comparisons seem to be based on the shape's volume, and it's `Shapes` that defines a `getVolume()` method, you should have `Shapes` implement `Comparable<Shapes>` and move the `compareTo(Shapes other)`  method to `Shapes`.

Comment: Yes, well, I was trying to keep things simple for someone who is still learning the basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *'... what can I do to fix the "AbstractShape.this cannot be referenced from a static context" error I am getting regarding my creation of cube1. ...'*

This is because you are working within a method marked for *[static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)* context.
The inner-class *Cube* requires an instance of its enclosing-class, *AbstractShape*; it's inferring *this* and cannot find the instance.

There are two things you can do, and it is dependent upon your data requirements.

If you plan on instantiating your *[nested-classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)* from outside of your *enclosing-class*, then mark them as *static.*

```java
static abstract class Shapes
static class Solids extends Shapes implements Comparable
static class Cube extends Solids
```

Otherwise, if *Cube* requires data specific to an instance of *AbstractShape*, just create an instance first.

```java
AbstractShape abstractShape = new AbstractShape();
Cube cube1 = abstractShape.new Cube(4,4,4);
cube1.calcArea();
cube1.print();
Solids [] MySolids = new Solids[2];
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding my knowledge a bit, good answer